# Defining a MonadEither type class

Tags: haskell, error-handling, monad-transformers

I'm going back through [Monad Transformers : Step by Step](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/personal/Transformers.pdf) as a refresher, and like many tutorials out there, it uses `Control.Monad.Error`. GHC now gives a warning that this module is deprecated, so I switched over to `Control.Monad.Trans.Either` from the `either` library: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/either-3.4/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Either.html

Everything is handled smoothly with `eval2` in the paper, since `EitherT` is the outermost monad. However, after that everything falls apart -- `ReaderT` is in no way an `Either` value, and everything henceforth uses `ErrorT`, which I'd like to change to `EitherT`.

My idea, then, was to define a `MonadEither` type class that boxed `left` and `right` in order to handle errors, but this hasn't been fruitful. I don't really understand how the type classes in `mtl` work, and this instance in particular has to be parameterized over multiple values, which is confusing. I came up with the following, which compiles after including some syntactic extensions:

```
class (Monad m) => MonadEither l r m | m -> r where
  right :: r -> m r
  left  :: l -> m r
```

But I can't figure out a `MonadEither` instance of `EitherT`:

```
instance Monad m => MonadEither l r (E.EitherT l m) where
  right = E.right
  left  = E.left
```

Edit: I changed the instance declaration to match `E.EitherT` properly, and get the following error message:

```
Illegal instance declaration for ‘MonadEither l r (E.EitherT l m)’
  The coverage condition fails in class ‘MonadEither’
    for functional dependency: ‘m -> r’
  Reason: lhs type ‘E.EitherT l m’ does not determine rhs type ‘r’
In the instance declaration for ‘MonadEither l r (E.EitherT l m)’
```

Again, I'm not really sure what I'm doing. I don't really understand functional dependencies, so I'm just looking for some guidance as to what an appropriate `MonadEither` type class might look like, if possible to define.

Comment: `MonadEither l r (E.EitherT l m)` is not a valid instance given that fundep, because you are saying "You can determine `r` uniquely given `m`" but you are also saying that `r` can be anything if `m` is the type `E.EitherT l m`; that is, you are saying there is no relation between `E.EitherT l m` and `r`, which is exactly what the error tells you.

Comment: @user2407038 That makes sense. This was my first time ever trying to program with functional dependencies, so the error was very foreign. Thanks for making sense of the message!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about

```
instance Monad m => MonadEither l r (E.EitherT l m)
```

That is, it should be `l` instead of `r`.

However once you've done this you'll come up across a separate error.  The root cause is that there's no point to `right`; it's just `return`.  This means you need to get rid of the `r` parameter to the class.

```
class Monad m => MonadEither l m where
    left  :: l -> m a
```

Your instance declaration should then become

```
instance Monad m => MonadEither l (E.EitherT l m)
```

(You also may want to look at the [`MonadError` class](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mtl-1.1.0.2/docs/Control-Monad-Error-Class.html) since this is essentially what you are replicating.)

Comment: I tried that as well (and that instance is MORE correct, so thanks for the catch), but still get an error -- I updated the question.

Comment: Correct, you don't need the definition for `right` or the class's `r` parameter at all.  I updated my answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: `MonadEither l r (E.EitherT l m)` should be `MonadEither l (E.EitherT l m)` -- I tried to edit the answer but it won't let me since it's only a character off!